# PowerShell: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: python, json, flask, post

I was trying to run my first command with POST method:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"flower":"1,2,3,7"}' http://localhost:5000/iris_post
```

But I got an error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)</p>
```

My code for POST method is very simple:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/iris_post', methods=['POST'])
def add_message():
    content = request.get_json()
    return str(content)
```

Where is the problem?

**UPD**:

It seems that I have a problem with my PowerShell. PowerShell doesn't have ***curl*** by default but I fixed it with ***Remove-item alias:curl***. I don't know why but it leads to the error above. The same command works fine in Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code and it worked smoothly here. In order to reproduce your error, I've replaced single quote argument by double quote in the POST data:

```
POST --data "{"flower":"1,2,3,7"}"
```

This way the error appeared here also. But using single quote, as you typed, it worked as expected. So it seems a typo error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that I have a problem with my PowerShell. PowerShell doesn't have ***curl*** by default but I fixed it with ***Remove-item alias:curl***. I don't know why but it leads to the error above. The same command works fine in Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the Invoke-RestMethod ?

```
$url = 'http://localhost:5000/iris_post'
data = '{"flower":"1,2,3,7"}'
Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method Post -Body $data -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```